# Twitter returns unauthorized for user timeline but not search

Tags: node.js, api, twitter, oauth

I've set up an app, and have taken both the consumer key and secret from the Application Settings page (https://apps.twitter.com/app/APP_ID/keys). The app has 'Read and write' permissions.

I've also generated an access token and secret for my user account on this page, though I have been through the steps of the Oauth flow, authorized the application and retrieved the same token and secret via that route too.

If I use these credentials to request from the search API (i.e. https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json) then I get a successful response. However, when doing the same from the user timeline endpoint, despite authorising the application, I get an HTTP401 response saying 'Not authorized.'

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
import request from 'request-promise';

const twitterOauthConfig = {
    consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token_key: 'MY USER TOKEN KEY',
    access_token_secret: 'MY USER TOKEN SECRET'
};

const getRequestOptions = (user, tag) => {
    return {
        uri: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json',
        qs: {
            q: `user_id=${user}&screen_name=${user}&tag=${tag}`
        },
        headers: {
            Accept: '*/*',
            Connection: 'close'
        },
        json: true,
        oauth: twitterOauthConfig
    };
}

const options = getRequestOptions('example_screen_name', 'example_hash_tag');
request(options)
    .then((response) => {
        // ...
    });
```

Does anyone know why I might be receiving that error?

Comment: I face a similar problem when using the Application-Only authentication too, and can recreate from Postman with the same data (removing the possibility of a bug in this specific code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now resolved this, TL;DR: I needed to check my application *and* user Access levels matched in the [Application Management panel](https://apps.twitter.com/) and regenerate my access token/secret.

> I get an HTTP401 response saying 'Not authorized.'

By comparing this to the [API docs around Error Codes & Responses](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) I saw that this had to be "Missing or incorrect authentication credentials".

I closely checked the Application Management panel of my app to check that I'd copied the keys/tokens/secrets correctly but also to see if there was any other discrepancies.

I noticed that my application Access Level was set to 'Read and write' but that my user's access token Access Level was only set to 'Read'.

By regenerating the Access token and secret on that page I was able to successfully retrieve my user timeline.

This doesn't make a *huge* amount of sense to me - given that both had the 'Read' access level originally I'm not sure why they need to match exactly, but it's fixed the problem.